# Why do I get an error in the loop in this code?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, file

I can do this with "for" loop, but why does it say it's outside of bounds of the array when I try with "for each"? The text file numbers are 9 2 1 3 4 4.

```
 string text = File.ReadAllText("txt.txt");         
            string[] bits = text.Split(' ');
            int[] numere = Array.ConvertAll(bits, int.Parse);
            

            
            foreach (int item in numere)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(numere[item]);
                
            }
```

Comment: Your array contains 6 item but you are trying to access index 9 in first iteration . So , you can not do that. Please try Console.WriteLine(item);

Comment: Using the [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in), `item` is an element of `numere`, you get `numere[0]` as `item`, next `numere[1]` as `item` and so on, you don't need to index like using a [for](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for). It is like in a tennis trial lesson: you get a ball, a ball, a ball... from the trainer or the machine, until the basket is empty. Thus the @ofirelarat answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the foreach function wrong.
In foreach loop you are **iterate the items value** of the collection each iteration,
so **the item variable in your case is the value of the cell** in that iteration and not his index (like in regular for loop).

It will look like this:

```
foreach (int item in numere)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```